# Getting Toolbar to host Items in an ItemsControl

Tags: wpf

I'd like to host custom items in a ToolBar in an ItemsControl.  However, the buttons I add are rendered below the toolbar and as regular buttons rather than in the ToolBar with the ToolBar look and feel.

This can be reproduced with a few lines of Xaml (I've excluded the default content).  The custom ItemsControl:

```
<ToolBar ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />
```

The example window:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <local:UserControl1>
        <Button>control button</Button>
    </local:UserControl1>
    <Button>standard button</Button>
    <ToolBar>
        <Button>window toolbar button</Button>
    </ToolBar>
```

I would expect that the "control button" would render similarly to the "window toolbar button", rather it renders like the "standard button" below an empty ToolBar.

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: dmo, did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Elmo - sorry I didn't post it earlier.

Answer (score 4):

set the style on the button like this:

```
Style="{DynamicResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}"
```

Comment: This gets the style right, but the button is still placed below the toolbar rather than in it.

Comment: Wow, that tip saved me a lot of work. I wanted to add a group of toolbar buttons bound to a data source, so I was embedding an ItemsControl in my toolbar, with a horizontal stack panel, and each item templated as a button, but they weren't appearing as normal toolbar buttons until I added this style.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting the behavior I wanted by naming the custom ToolBar, then adding a property in the code-behind that could be used by consumers of the control to add items through code.